# Django WSGI No module named 'site'

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I've searched, tried and ran almost every tutorial available to run my django application with apache or even nginx (most of which are over 3 or 4 years old).

I've managed to pull through and get parts of everything to work with nginx until I gave up, now I'm trying with apache2, the only error so far I'm having is with wsgi.py, everything else works fine, but running

```
sudo python3 -i /var/www/shinra/shinra/wsgi.py
```

gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/shinra/shinra/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'shinra'
```

My wsgi.py is set as follows:

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/var/www/shinra'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "shinra.settings")
def execfile(filename):
     globals = dict( __file__ = filename )
     exec( open(filename).read(), globals )

activate_this = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'env/shinra/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this )
```

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

I've also tried running it with the default wsgi.py to no avail.
As for the rest of the project, it's just a brand new django project, nothing else in there has been modified other than putting the virtual envirnoment inside `/var/www/shinra/env/shinra/bin`. Thank you, I've been fighting with this for a while and I'm new to django. Running this with apache2 obviously yields the same error in the apache logs.

**EDIT:** It would also be good to mention that I'm trying to run this in an amazon web services EC2 Instance

**UPDATE:**

I tried doing everything from scratch using gunicorn again, so far it works if im on my virtual environment and run

```
/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/shinra/scripts/gunicorn_config.py shinra.wsgi
```

But if I to set that using supervisor I get this error:

```
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10320] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10320] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (10320)
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10320] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10323] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10323
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10323] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'shinra'
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10323] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10323)
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10320] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-06-21 05:15:25 +0000] [10320] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The gunicorn config file is:

```
command = '/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/bin/python'
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
workers = 3
```

Comment: You can't run a ``wsgi.py`` directly with Python usually. For Apache the Django instructions are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ There is nothing in your question to suggest what you set up, so is impossible to give any guidance on what may not have worked for Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! My configuration for the supervisor was missing a few parameters:

```
[program:shinra_gunicorn]
command=/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/shinra/gunicorn_config.py shinra.wsgi
directory=/home/ubuntu/shinra
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/venvs/shinra/bin"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/shinra.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/shinra.out.log
```